# sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) is not working while selecting location on Naukri homepage

Tags: selenium, arrow-keys

I am new to selenium. I am trying to automate Naukri homepage.
However, in the field location, sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) is not working. Code is working fine till a.sendKeys("ch").
I am using below code. Please guide.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='sugInp']")).sendKeys("java");
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='Sdrop']/li/div/strong"));
        
        for(WebElement o:options)
        {
            if(o.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("developer"))
            {
                o.click();
                System.out.println("success");
                break;
            }
            
        }
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);

           Robot r = new Robot();
           r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
           System.out.println("Tab success");
           
           Actions a = new Actions(driver);
           a.sendKeys("ch");
           a.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
           a.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
           a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
           a.build().perform();
```

Comment: So basically want to select a location which you are unable to do, is that right ?

Comment: @theNishant I am able to navigate till Location field. Then I enter a few alphabets and based on that, I want to select a location from the options that appear. I am trying to do this, by using keys.ARROW_DOWN. However this is not working. Options appear, but arrow keys don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss your element. Please try this one.

```
WebElement txtUsername = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action seriesOfActions = builder
    .moveToElement(txtUsername)
    .click()
    .keyDown(txtUsername, Keys.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys(txtUsername, "hello")
    .keyUp(txtUsername, Keys.SHIFT)
    .doubleClick(txtUsername)
    .contextClick()
    .build();
    
seriesOfActions.perform() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just click on the desired element from the list, instead of using `Actions`

This is how it will look without `Actions`

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='sugInp']")).sendKeys("java");
Thread.sleep(2000);List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='Sdrop']/li/div/strong"));
        for (WebElement o : options) {
            if (o.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("developer")) {
                o.click();
                System.out.println("success");
                break;
            }
         }
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#qsb-location-sugg.sugInp")).sendKeys("ch");
Thread.sleep(3000);
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sugDrp_qsb-location-sugg']/ul/li"));
System.out.println(elements.get(1).getText());
elements.get(1).click();
```

And don't use Thread.sleep() anywhere in your script, make sure to use waits.